# I am trying to show checkbox checked unchecked based on is active true false value from database in datatable but I am not able to do that

Tags: jquery, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to show checkbox checked unchecked from database value but I am not ablt to find any solution.Kindly help me in that.

Below is the code I have tried

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="tblBrand">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Brand Name</th>
            <th>ISActive</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetBrand", "Product")',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (result) {


                var data = result.brandList;
                BindBrand(data);


            }
    });
    });



    function BindBrand(msg) {

        var properties = {
            bProcessing: true,
            bDestroy: true,
            bSort: true,
            data: msg,
            aoColumns: [
                { mData: 'GlobalCodeName' },
                {
                    mData: "",
                    bSortable: false,
                    mRender: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        if (rowObject.IsActive === true) {
                            $('input:checked');
                        }


                        debugger;
                        return '<input id="checkid' + rowObject.GlobalCodeID + '" class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" onchange="Updatecheckboxvalue(' + rowObject.GlobalCodeID + ');"></input> ';

                    }
                }

            ]
        };
        var table = $('#tblBrand').DataTable(properties);


    }
</script>
```

Above is the code in view

And Below is the code in controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetBrand()
    {
        var finalResult = Common.GetProductBrand("1001");
        var JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalResult);
        var brandList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<GlobalCodes>>(JSONString);

        //return Json(brandList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return Json(new { brandList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I want that in my view Checkbox should be checked if IsActive column in my database is true and if it is false then checkbox values should be false

Comment: What is the type of is active?

Answer (score 0):

Let try this way:

```
    mRender: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    debugger;
    return '<input id="checkid' + rowObject.GlobalCodeID + '" class="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" onchange="Updatecheckboxvalue(' + rowObject.GlobalCodeID + ');" ' + (rowObject.IsActive === true)?'checked':'' + '>';

  }
```